# Button click event not working on login screen

Tags: android

when i click the button i cannot go to the next activity..but if the remove the compare string..the intent works fine..can anyone please help me figuring out what's wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button b1;
    private EditText et;
    String s;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        s = et.getText().toString();
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickhere);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(et.getText().toString().equals(R.string.Ronnie))
                {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Thought.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not for you",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: if(et.getText().toString().equals(R.string.Ronnie)) replace this line with this
if(et.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.Ronnie)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing and `int id` to a `String`.

```
 if(et.getText().toString().equals(R.string.Ronnie))
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Thought.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not for you",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
```

Change this to .

```
 if(et.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.Ronnie)))
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Thought.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not for you",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

Comment: If its solved your issue then pls accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(et.getText().toString().trim().equals(getString(R.string.Ronnie).trim()))
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Thought.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not for you",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```